# Exporting data from points to a polygon

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

I'm new on GIS.

We were migrating from an old map program to QGIS.

My problem is that I need to have Polygons with data.

And I have the information that I need in the polygons in "entities" points. ("Text" is the information that I need on my polygon below).

[image]

Polygons has not "UniqueID" so I can't join information from Key fields. So there are no attributes in them.

[image]

I just need the information the points to the polygons below.

I've tried to join attributes by location. But is not working.

This is the layer with the information that I need.
[image]

And here's the polygon that I need the information.
[image]

When I try to join attributes by location I get this:
[image]
There are the titles but not the information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As we can see on your screenshots, your layers don't have CRS. You need to set the coordinate system first.

Comment: You're right! @katagena! I changed it ! Thank you so much!

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key features of GIS is to be able to do a *spatial* join. So you don't need a primary key like you would in a standard relational database.

You can use QGIS to do a "spatial join" which will join the points with the polygon that contains them:

Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join Attributes by Location

[image]

Make sure you choose the correct layers, geometric predicate and join type for your specific data.

Comment: Thank you, Dave! Seems that's what I need to go for.

I'm still having trouble. It did not work. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I'm going to edit more the question as I can't give images here.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like greetings within your posts.